# Spring findBy query method to find enabled countries together with the country containing a certain city

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have classes `Country` and `City`:

The `Country` class has the properties:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
private Set<City> cities;

private boolean enabled;
```

Now I need to find all enabled countries together with the country containing a certain city:

Not this one:

```
findDistinctByEnabledOrCitiesNotNull(boolean enabled)
```

because in this case I find enabled countries together with all disabled countries containing cities.

I need something like:

```
findByEnabledOrCitiesContaining(boolean enabled, City city)
```

Is it possible?

---

SQL would be something like this:

```
select country.id, country.name, country.enabled from country
left join city on city.countryid = country.id
where country.enabled = 1 or city.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. My method `findByEnabledOrCitiesContaining(boolean enabled, City city)` is the solution. It just didn't work because of something else.

So, this question needs no more answers and may be closed.

Thank you!

Comment: I know I can delete. I just let it stay together with the answer if someone else has the same question. If moderators think it may not stay, that's another question. I cannot mark my own answer as accepted.

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted, you just [have to wait 48 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) before doing so.